# Scanf into pointer

Tags: c, pointers, scanf, undefined-behavior, string-literals

I have this code:

```
char *ps = "hello";
scanf("%s", ps);
```

I want to write a string, let's pretend "a", to pointer without using an array. Trying to scanf a string into ps causes error *interrupted by signal 10: SIGBUS*. I'd be happy to hear an explanation for such a behavior.

Comment: `ps` points to a *read-only* area of memory (where the array/string `"hello"` is stored). To have the compiler warn about it, some people use `const char *ps = "hello";` You probably want `char *ps = malloc(100); scanf("%99s", ps); /* use ps */ free(ps);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pointer points to a string literal

```
char *ps = "hello";
```

So this call

```
scanf("%s", ps);
```

tries to change a string literal.

You may not change string literals. Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior.

From the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals)

> 7 It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
> elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to
> modify such an array, the behavior is undefined**